# iOS notification and server cheking

Tags: ios, web-services, background, gps

I'm making a program for IOS for the first time. I never had a iPhone so I don't really get how it works...

I want to make my system able to call a webservice on the background and depending in the answer show a notification.

How can I do this?
I read on the Internet that I can push notifications to the phone, however that won't solve my problem because I want my server to track the user position, so it need the user to silently tell the server it's gps coordinates.

Thank you,
GustDD

Comment: Notification as in a notification center?

Comment: Notification as in any kind of it =) A pop-up or a sound...

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest building the app first to run in the foreground. I will assume you already understand how to use the GPS, so will not go into detail on that.

First off, you will need to write the server backend and app pretty much simultaneously. There are many choices for writing the server backend language wise. I prefer python, others ruby on rails. You want to build a [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) for the server that the iDevice can talk to with simple HTTP protocol.

You must decide on the API. You must think about what kind of data you will want to send and receive and how you will wrap the data. Also what HTTP protocols will you be using for specific requests, like GET POST etc. Furthermore, you will have to decide at what URL's on the server will it be useful to GET or POST to depending on the data you want to send or receive. I would suggest you use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) to wrap your data. It is quite intuitive and easy to encode and decode.

Next you will have to decide how to talk to the server in iOS. There are many great third party libraries that dress up [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or you can use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) itself (sometimes a bit tedious). I personally like to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It will do the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) decoding and encoding for you which is a big bonus.

Finally, once you have the two communicating with how you want and with the data you want, now time to dress it up. You can allow your app to run in the background and collect GPS data and send it. You can also use the notification center to display information it gets from the server in the background.

**Update to Comment**

[This will be extremely helpful](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) for you with background programming. From an Android perspective, iOS is a little bit different since there is not really a direct correlation for Android services in iOS. Every little detail to put your project together is in that link.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have taken care of all the things till the foreground/background part. I have done other projects on Android and such. The problem is, can I make a app start when the device is turn on and run on background without being closed? How do I do it?

Comment: @Gust check out my update, that link should be quite helpful.

Comment: I had already studied that page... But none of the solution present there is good for me... I need to trade information with the server in each 30 mins, how can I wake my application up, without taking it to the foreground to update the server?